# El significado de "frente a"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera saber el significado de "frente a" en el siguiente [párrafo](https://www.20minutos.es/noticia/4105300/0/vacunas-no-financiadas-sanidad-aconsejan-pediatras/?autoref=true), que aparece 2 veces. La preposición se traduce en inglés como "facing", pero no consigo entender el párrafo con esta traducción. ¿Se puede substituir "frente a" por otra palabra u otras palabras en este contexto para poder entenderlo mejor? ¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda por adelantado!

"Se felicita por que el Ministerio de Sanidad haya elaborado un 'Calendario común para toda la vida' al que ha incorporado en los últimos años la vacunación antineumocócica y frente a la varicela, el adelanto a los 12 años de la inmunización frente al virus del papiloma humano (VPH) en chicas y contra el meningococo (A,C, W, Y)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresion ["frente a"](https://dle.rae.es/frente?m=form) significa `contra o en contra de algo o alguien`
De la frase puede entenderse que (alguien):

> destaca el mérito  del Ministerio de Sanidad, por su acción positiva en la elaboración de un calendario común universal (que cubra todas las vacunaciones necesarias en la vida de una persona). Y, dentro de ese calendario, la incorporación de:
>
> - la vacuna antineumocócica
> - la usada "**contra**" la varicela
> - la inmunización a los 12 años del virus del papiloma humano (VPH), en niñas
> - y la inumnización contra el miningococo (A, C, W, Y)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones! Quisiera preguntarle sobre el significado de "la usada" en "la usada 'contra' la varicela". Gracias otra vez.

Comment: Puede entenderse que es "la (*vacuna*) **empleada** contra la varicela"

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda otra vez, IPP! Saludos